# application of Riemann's theorem on removable singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory, singularity

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway. I managed to prove the first part of (a), but I can't understand the second part of (a). How can it be possible that f(a) belongs to the boundary of Ω? By the Open Mapping theorem, I think both f(G-{a}) and f(G) are open sets... Or is there a possibility that the second part of (a) is a typo? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I don't understand the question, since $a$ does not belong to the domain of $f$.

Comment: a is an removable singularity so f can be defined as an analytic function on the whole G.

Comment: If $f$ is one-to-one $G \to U$ then $f$  is one-to-one $G -\{a\} \to U  - \{f(a)\} = \Omega$ and $f(a) \in \partial \Omega$. @JoséCarlosSantos It does since $z=a$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: @Keith use latex

Comment: @reuns Sure. I suggest that you post that as an answer.

Comment: This is supposed to be an hint to help the OP.

Comment: Oh, i got confused. There are ways in which boundary points are added and the set is still open....Thank you for your comments anyway.